# How to select discontinuity (not continued/separated/not in range) text in Visual Studio code?

Tags: windows-11, visual-studio-code, ide

How to select discontinuity (not continued/separated/not in range) text in Visual Studio code?
Hey,
I want to select specific characters in specific lines in Visual Studio.
For example, in this code block, I want to select the text only in line 3 and lines 5:

```c
printf("Lines 1 \n");
printf("Lines 2 \n");
printf("Lines 3 \n");
printf("Lines 4 \n");
printf("Lines 5 \n");
```

I don't know if this is an option also to Windows as this will be a huge bonus.

Comment: With the mouse use <ctrl> to add the 2nd selection

Comment: Looking at your tags, Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are COMPLETELY different products that don't share a single line of source code.  Which is it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @SeñorCMasMas I meant VSCODE.

Comment: @DavidPostill Your suggestion does not work. I wish this was the option for me as this is the same as  how I select separate not in range files in windows explorer.

Comment: Nice to edit your tags and not respond in comment alone.  Have a great day! :)

Comment: Hmm, the question is about visual studio code. I changed the tags to update you. Sorry if this was not clear enough for you.

Comment: Why exactly did you downvote my answer @Eyal Cohen? It does exactly what you want... Are you serious?

Comment: After searching @Destroy666 is the correct answer. Can you edit your comment, so I can upvote it again?
I had this option blocked for some reason after resetting + updating my VS Code, your answer works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> by default. See the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor) for more info

> VS Code supports multiple cursors for fast simultaneous edits. You can add secondary cursors (rendered
> thinner) with `Alt+Click`. Each cursor operates independently based on
> the context it sits in. A common way to add more cursors is with
> `Ctrl+Alt+Down` or `Ctrl+Alt+Up` that insert cursors below or above.
>
> If you'd like to change the modifier key for applying multiple cursors
> to `Cmd+Click` on macOS and `Ctrl+Click` on Windows and Linux, you can do
> so with the `editor.multiCursorModifier` setting. This lets users coming
> from other editors such as Sublime Text or Atom continue to use the
> keyboard modifier they are familiar with.
>
> The setting can be set to:
>
> `ctrlCmd` - Maps to `Ctrl` on Windows and `Cmd` on macOS.
>
> `alt` - The existing default `Alt`.